# player.mute() doesn't work on ios

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, youtube, youtube-api

I have a page with a youtube video. I want to mute it when it plays. player.mute() works on android n desktop but doesn't on ipad (iphone will make the video fullscreen). Is there any way around it to make the video plays without sound? I'm trying to avoid uploading the video without any sound.

my js:

```
$('#container.click-to-play-video').click(function(){
    $('#start').delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        width : '100%',
        height : '100%',
        videoId : 'gq5KvRZpS6I',
        playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls':0, 'rel':0, 'showinfo':0 },
        events : {
            'onReady' : onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange' : onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
});
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    player.mute();
}
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if(event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
        player.destroy();
    }
}
```

the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/framelita/angqtmrc/

the page sample: http://framelita.com/staging/youtube/